# Whether to clone an object for a prototype

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the following two ways to define a prototype, and is one more correct than the other?

```js
// prototype
const animal = {
    breathe() {console.log('The animal is breathing.')},
}
// construtor
function Dog(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype = animal; // without Object.create()

let a = new Dog('Annie');
a.breathe();
```

```js
// prototype
const animal = {
    breathe() {console.log('The animal is breathing.')},
}
// construtor
function Dog(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype = Object.create(animal); // with Object.create

let a = new Dog('Annie');
a.breathe();
```

Why would one be more preferable over the other (especially if it is a `const` object)?

Comment: You may find [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) easier to use.

Comment: Try creating also a `Cat` class with a prototype, which should also inherit from `animal`, and try to give them different methods. Compare the outcomes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your first example, when you create `a` you get the following object structure:

```
      +------------------+      +-----animal-----+      +-------------------+
a --->|  [[Prototype]] -------->|  [[Prototype]]------->|  Object.prototype |
      |  name: 'Annie'   |      |  breathe() {}  |      |                   |
      +------------------+      +----------------+      +-------------------+
```

This occurs because `Dog`'s `prototype` is `animal` (`Dog.prototype === animal`), so when you create a new instance of Dog (ie: `a`), its `[[Prototype]]` is set to `animal`. This can be problematic if you want to add some new additional fields/logic to `Dog`'s prototype so that anything inheriting from `Dog` would also have these methods:

```js
const animal = {
  breathe() {console.log('The animal is breathing.')},
}
// construtor
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype = animal; // without Object.create()
Dog.prototype.bark = () => console.log("Woof!"); // this updates  `animal` also (not good!)

let a = new Dog('Annie');
a.breathe();
a.bark();
```

In the above example, we added a new `bark` method to the `Dog`'s `prototype`, which we know points to `animal`. Because it points to the `animal` object you'll be adding the `bark` method to the `animal` object. Even though `animal` is declared as `const`, this doesn't stop new properties from being added to the object it references, all it does in terms of immutability is prevent reassignment of the `animal` variable later on in your code. The problem now that `animal` has changed is that any other function constructors that you may have had in your code that also have had their `prototype` set to the `animal` object will now have the new `bark` method. For example, if you had something like: `Turtle.prototype = animal;` also in your code, then all `Turtle` instances would also have `bark()`.

Your second example that uses `Object.create()` creates a new object with its `[[Prototype]]` set to the animal object. This new object adds a layer of "padding", which means you can update the `Dog.prototype` as you're updating the new object that `Object.create()` creates for you and not the `animal` reference. Your second example has the following memory structure:

```
      +------------------+      +----------------+      +------animal-------+
a --->|  [[Prototype]] -------->|  [[Prototype]]------->|   [[Prototype]]---------+
      |  name: 'Annie'   |      |  <empty>       |      |    breathe() {}   |     |
      +------------------+      +----------------+      +-------------------+     |
                                                                                  |
      +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      v
      +------------------+
      | Object.prototype |
      |                  |
      +------------------+
```

Here the empty object is set as the `[[Prototype]]` of `a` because `Dog`'s `.prototype` is set to the empty object created with `Object.create()`. The empty object also has a `[[Prototype]]` of `animal` as that was passed as the first argument to `Object.create(animal)`. By adding a `bark()` method to the empty object you're no lonnger impacting the `animal` object anymore, which means you no longer will have mutant turtles/instances that can "bark". With that in mind, use `Object.create(animal)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Object.create` adds an extra level to your prototype chain.  The dog prototype will be an object with its prototype set to animal.

`dog -> empty_object -> animal -> Object -> null`

The first way is missing that extra object.

`dog -> animal -> Object -> null`

So if you want to add more functionality to just the dog, without adding to the animal, you need the former.  Otherwise not needed.